# How do I format the date and time That is received from database

Tags: php, date, formatting

Iam getting the date and time from Database as follows

Date : 20100101(YYYY/MM/DD)
Time : 120912 (HH:MM:SS)

I have to format the Date as follows   20100101 --> (2010-10-11) (look to have ) "-" in between year and month and Day

I have to format the time as follows   120912 --> 12:02:12 suppose I may have the time as 62367  from the database

06:23:67

Comment: what database you're using? I've never heard of DBMS called "Database"

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you convert the data using: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: I think it's easier to do this in PHP than in SQL

Answer (score 0):

we can use `DATE_FORMAT(fieldname,format )` function in mysql
For Example we can use `DATE_FORMAT( a.date, '%d-%m-%Y' )`