# How to set date and time format in timestamp field

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format the date and time That is received from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632747/how-do-i-format-the-date-and-time-that-is-received-from-database)

[Output of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUo7A.jpg)

I want to show only date in "In Comming Date" column and only time in "In Comming Time" 
my code is this can anybody help me i m a newbie

```
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password)
or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Opps some thing went wrong");
$sql="SELECT * FROM `hr_inout_time` WHERE user_id='$login_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "<table align='center' border='1' cellspacing='5'  width='50%' height='50%'>
<th>In Comming Date</th> 
<th>In Comming Time</th> 
";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $in_time=$row["user_in_time"];
    $time_date =$row["time_date"];
    echo "<tr>
            <td align='center'>$time_date</td> 
             <td align='center'>$in_time</td> 
         </tr>";
    }
echo('</table>');
?>
```

Comment: don't use mysql functions unless you are forced to use a old PHP version! use mysqli or PDO instead ^^

Comment: BTW: not: `echo "<a lot of html tags>$and_vars</a lot.../>"` but: `<a lot...><?php echo $and_vars; ?></a lot...>`. Readable and optimized code.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - Replace:

```
<td align='center'>$time_date</td> 
<td align='center'>$in_time</td>
```

With

```
<td align='center'>".explode(" ",$time_date)[0]."</td> 
<td align='center'>".explode(" ",$in_time)[1]."</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
$in_time=$row["user_in_time"];
$time_date =$row["time_date"];
```

to

```
$in_time = date('H:i', strtotime($row["user_in_time"]));
$time_date = date('d F Y', strtotime($row["time_date"]));
```

Change `H:i` and `d F Y` to your preferred date / time formats.

Comment: Thanx a lot stealthyninja its working fine as i want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all with SQL, so you don't need to have conversions in your PHP script. Since your dates look to be stored as DATETIME values, you can use the DATE() and TIME() functions to return just those portions of the value

```
$sql = "SELECT hr_inout_time.*, 
  DATE(hr_inout_time.time_date) as time_date, 
  TIME(hr_inout_time.user_in_time) as user_in_time 
FROM `hr_inout_time` 
WHERE user_id='$login_id'";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$in_time = $row["user_in_time"];

$time_date = $row["time_date"];
```

to:

```
$in_time = date('H:i:s', strtotime($row["user_in_time"]));

$time_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row["time_date"]));
```